# Regex to select table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012.

The below query fetches all the schema and the corresponding tables that exist in a container DB :

```
select  table_schema,TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where        
TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('cdc') and table_type in ('base table','view')
```

[image]

The cdc schema is as follows :

[image]

The facts :

1. The cdc schema has two Change Tables (CT)(data_personnel_ct, datalake_personnel_new_ct) for ONE table(dbo.datalake_personnel) in the dbo schema
2. There can be two(or more, in future) CT for a table in any of the schemas

I am trying to write a query which provides the **list of all the CT tables under the cdc schema based on ALL the tables found in the other schema** but I dunno how to include a regex(if possible, some thing like *SchemaName_TableName_NEW_CT*) in the select clause(*the below query selects only one CT table*) :

```
select TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME,TABLE_TYPE from information_schema.tables where
TABLE_SCHEMA in ('cdc') 
and table_name in (select  table_schema+'_'+TABLE_NAME+'_'+'CT' from information_schema.tables where        
TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('cdc') and table_type in ('base table','view'))
order by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.TABLE_CATALOG, t1.TABLE_SCHEMA, t1.TABLE_NAME, t1.TABLE_TYPE 
from information_schema.tables as t1
inner join
(
    select table_schema+'_'+TABLE_NAME as TableName 
    from information_schema.tables 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA  <> 'cdc' 
    and table_type in ('base table','view')
) as t2
on t1.TableName LIKE t2.TableName +'%CT'
where t1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cdc'
order by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Since the query returned multiple rows and I just want the CT tables under cdc, I modified your query to get the output, can you once verify if I have done it correctly ?

select distinct t1.TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.tables as t1
inner join
(
    select table_schema+'_'+TABLE_NAME as TableName 
    from information_schema.tables 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA  <> 'cdc' 
    and table_type in ('base table','view')
) as t2
on REVERSE (t1.Table_Name) LIKE 'TC%'
where t1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cdc';

Comment: Seems ok to me. Can you test to see if Binyamin Regev's suggestion is correct? Is it really faster with the `REVERSE` or without it?

Comment: Err...both the queries return almost immediately, do you want me to compare the times shown by SQL Server Mgt. Studio to execute the queries ?

Comment: No, not really. I would be surprised if there was a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Take Zohar Peled code and make it work faster using `reverse` string function:

```
on REVERSE (t1.TableName) LIKE 'TC%'
```

You save the strings concatinating and `LIKE 'TC%'` works faster than `LIKE '%CT'`

Comment: I have modified @Zohar's query and also added the REVERSE, can you once verify ?

select distinct t1.TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.tables as t1
inner join
(
    select table_schema+'_'+TABLE_NAME as TableName 
    from information_schema.tables 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA  <> 'cdc' 
    and table_type in ('base table','view')
) as t2
on REVERSE (t1.Table_Name) LIKE 'TC%'
where t1.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cdc';

Comment: This would have been better as a comment to my answer. However, I'm not so sure it's correct. It's true that if the LIKE operator only contains wildcards after the beginning of the string sql server can still use whatever index is on the column, However once you have the REVERSE on the column name it prevents the use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

the below will only work providing:

- i have understood the question correctly!
- all your tables end with ct

you can use `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` and add in a % sign to say I am searching for everything ending with ct.

`table_name NOT LIKE '%ct'` would return all tables that don't have ct at the end of their name

`table_name LIKE '%ct'` would return all tables that have ct at the end of their name

you can also do `table_name LIKE '%ct%'` which would return all tables that contain the letter ct (this is of course least optimal)

```
    select 
    TABLE_CATALOG
    ,TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,TABLE_NAME
    ,TABLE_TYPE 
from information_schema.tables 
where
    TABLE_SCHEMA in ('cdc')  and
        (table_name not like '%ct' and TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('cdc') and table_type in ('base table','view'))

order by 
    TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
first it create a temp table contains all Change Table (CT) names and then try to check if there are matchings in cdc schema

```
create table #temp(tempName varchar(1000))
GO
Insert into #temp
select a.name + '_' + b.name + '_CT' from 
sys.schemas a
left join
sys.tables b on a.schema_id = b.schema_id
where a.name != 'cdc'

select * from #temp
GO


select * from
sys.schemas a
left join
sys.tables b on a.schema_id = b.schema_id
left join 
#temp c on c.tempName = b.name
where c.tempName != null and a.name = 'cdc'

Drop table #temp
```